# Extract values from a column in a Dataframe based in starting letters

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, dataframe

Hope everyone is doing well. I am using pandas and numpy and I would like to extract column values based on the first 3 letters (ap.) from a Dataframe. Below is an example of my Dataframe.

| Name | Number |
| --- | --- |
| Orange | 2 |
| APple | 6 |
| Ap.ricot | 1 |
| AP.19 | 1 |
| Juap.rte | 3 |

I've tried df[df['Name'].str.lower().str.contains('ap.', na=False)].Name.unique() but it does not fully do the trick.

Output:

```
['AP.19','Ap.ricot']
```

The output should ideally be a list that I can then save onto a variable. Additionally, the 3 letters need to be at the start and in this order.

I am very new to Python so please explain as clearly as possible. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to take out values where your code finds 'Ap' only?

Comment: No, I would like to extract the values in a list form, which start with 'ap.'

Of course, would also need to convert everything to lower case, but the output so be in its original form.

So exactly the output I have, otherwise have 'Ap' would also include 'APple'.

Comment: please check my answer once.

Comment: You can also try using `Match`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
df[df['Name'].str.match('^(ap[.])', case=False)].Name.unique()
```

---

```
array(['Ap.ricot', 'AP.19'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: I like the use of regex here :) Merry Xmas :D +5

Answer (score 2):

Given the comments in the post, I believe you can get it done with:

```
ap = [x for x in df['Name'] if x.lower().startswith('ap.')]
```

And if you wish to not have duplicates, then you can use:

```
ap = [x for x in df['Name'].unique() if x.lower().startswith('ap.')]
```

Comment: Thank you @Celius Stingher

That is exactly what I was looking for. Wish you a nice day.

Comment: Have a great day and Merry Christmas! Feel free to mark my answer as accepted so we know the problem has been solved!

Answer (score 1):

This may help you:

```
final = []


df['NameCopy'] = df['Name'].str.lower()


for index,row in df.iterrows():
   if row['NameCopy'].find('ap.') != -1:
      final += [row['Name']]
   else:
      pass

print(final)
```

Comment: Thank you!

This also works. I will accept and approve the answer as soon as StackOverflow allows me.

Comment: This is very inefficient as it is looping over a dataframe and should be discouraged.

Comment: Yes agree to @CeliusStingher: One should avoid iterating. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/6660373 btw merry Christmas to all of you in advance :)

Comment: @CeliusStingher: Good point, but such loops are better where there are more conditions you need to loop through within the same iteration. Which is why I prefer using these in my datasets.

Comment: You should avoid that. Visit the link that I have mentioned. It will help you in future :)

Comment: There is no conditions which you need to meet, and it has been proven many times there are vectorized ways of dealing with conditions such as `np.where()`. Using for loops should be avoided and discouraged when dealing with pandas dfs